# CSS image border transparency/color issue

Tags: css, image, border

I wanted to make a cool div, so I made this image to get its borders:

[image: mockup]

The problem is that half of the borders are transparent area, so when I try to fill the empty center of the div with background-color it also paints the outer, transparent area. I'd like the background color not to get past the border.

Here's what I'm talking about:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#testDiv{
 border-image-source:url(https://s9.postimg.org/40j461sf3/Div_Sprite.png);
 border-image-slice: 50% 25% 25%;
    border-image-repeat:repeat;
 border-image-width:auto;
 border-image-repeat:round;
    background-color: red;
    
 min-height:600px;
 width:600px;
}

#body {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #CCC;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="testDiv">

</div>
```

<sup>Or see http://jsfiddle.net/6M59T/119/.</sup>

How can I solve this? I've thought on putting a slightly smaller div inside this one, but I don't know how to adjust it so it always covers a bit less than its parent. Also, I'd like to keep it as simple as possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe i am mistaken, but you can try to play with `border-image-outset` and `margin` attribute.

```
float:left;
margin:50px 20px;
border-image-source:url(http://s9.postimg.org/40j461sf3/Div_Sprite.png);
border-image-slice: 50% 25% 25%;
border-image-repeat:repeat;
border-image-width:auto;
border-image-repeat:round;
background-color: red;
border-image-outset:30px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6M59T/120/

Comment: Damn, just what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: well, i dont know specifics of border-image-xxx, i found answer at w3school :)